# Flagging summary improvement : clear view

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, flags, flag-history

On the flagging summary, it is not always easy to distinguish one flag from another. We don't know where it starts or finish.

I would suggest to add the dotted line (the one that already separates questions in the main list) just right after the actions that has been taken on the flag question/answer.

This would ease the reading of reviewers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be implemented now! Thanks!